# How to handle MMException from NAudio after Mic is unplugged during recording

Tags: .net, audio-recording, naudio, unhandled-exception

I am working on an windows forms program which listens to all of the active audio input devices using NAudio. The problem I am running into is if an there is only one audio input device is plugged in at the beginning of recording then is removed before the recording ends I received an unhandled `MMException` with an `MMResult` of `MMResult.NoDriver`.

Since I am using the `WaveIn.StartRecording()` method, which works in another thread I assume, the exception gets thrown up to the main method without being caught.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to safely continue recording or maybe stop the recording until the device is plugged back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution in the [NAudio discussion](http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/274165).

You need to get the source code fix (aka fork) from [here](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/bobasaurus/recordingPullCableFix) and compile it (only x86) for yourself.

> **bobasaurus:** This just changes part of the wavein callback code to cleanly stop recording if the recording device has a problem (like being disabled from pulling the cable on some Win 7 boxes).  It will call the RecordingStopped event when this happens.  I implemented this event handler in my main program's GUI controller, which, if it detects that WaveIn.DeviceCount is 0, will start a timer that will poll WaveIn.DeviceCount until it's back above 0 and restart the recording.